# Django - The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: python, django, windows, virtualenv, django-compressor

I'm trying to run Django on my Windows 10, I'm sort of newbie on Django, I'm using Compressor Toolkit, my problem is, I can run the manage.py but the localhost says

> base.html, error at line 9 The process cannot access the file because
>   it is being used by another process.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    {% load compress %}
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, inital-scale=1"/>
        <title>{% block head_title %} Hydroqua Indonesia {% endblock head_title %}</title>
        {% compress css %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/x-scss" href="{% static '/css/global.scss' %}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/x-scss" href="{% static '/css/style.scss' %}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
        {% endcompress %}
      </head>
      <body>
          {% include 'navbar.html' %}
          {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
        {% compress js %}
```

My friend could run the compressor smoothly from his Linux, I've installed every component needed but I dont know if I missed some.

Comment: Do you have the file open in an editor?

Comment: Thanks for the answer but no..

Comment: File access in Windows requires explicitly declaring whether read/execute, write/append, and delete/rename access will be shared with subsequent attempts to open the file, including within the same process. You have to find out which file it's complaining about and see which process has an open handle for it (e.g. using Process Explorer). If it's another process, closing it will solve the immediate problem. If it's your own process, you can modify the shared access or how you're using the file to work around the problem.

Comment: You can use [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx), [LockHunter](https://lockhunter.com/), or a similar program to figure out which process has the file in use.