# Form errors not displaying in UpdateView

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have an UpdateView that will display a form to either create the user profile or update the user profile. It works well, however, for some reason I can't get it to show the form errors. There should be form errors based on the `ValidationErrors` I have put in the model form. I suspect my views.py to be the cause of the form not displaying the errors.

Here's my view:

```
class ProfileSettings(UpdateView):
    model = Profile
    template_name = 'profile/settings.html'
    form_class = ProfileForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('profile:settings')

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            bio = form.cleaned_data['bio']
            gender = form.cleaned_data['gender']
            avatar = form.cleaned_data['avatar']


            Profile.objects.update_or_create(user=self.request.user, defaults={'avatar':avatar, 'bio':bio, 'gender':gender})

        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.success_url)
```

In the template, I am displaying the errors like so: `{{ form.avatar.errors }}` where avatar should display an error if the image is too small, but it doesn't.

Comment: show us forms.py. Also are you rendering form in your template ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, you are not returning the form errors to the template. I think you can approach like this(overriding `form_valid` instead of `post` method):

```
class ProfileSettings(UpdateView):
    model = Profile
    template_name = 'profile/settings.html'
    form_class = ProfileForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('profile:settings')

   def form_valid(self, form):
      bio = form.cleaned_data['bio']
      gender = form.cleaned_data['gender']
      avatar = form.cleaned_data['avatar']
      Profile.objects.update_or_create(user=self.request.user, defaults={'avatar':avatar, 'bio':bio, 'gender':gender})
      return HttpResponseRedirect(self.success_url)
```

BTW, there are some flaws with this code as well. We are not using model form's `save` here. It would be best if we could use that. `form_valid` originally does that.

Also on another note, I think its best to use [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/signals/) to create the user profile whenever the user is created. Here is a [medium post](https://medium.com/@bencleary/django-user-profiles-f5c9aedb70db) on how to do that. In that way, you don't even need to override `form_valid`.

### Update

Using FormView to pre-populate data:

```
class ProfileSettings(FormView):
    model = Profile
    template_name = 'profile/settings.html'
    form_class = ProfileForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('profile:settings')

   def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(ProfileSettings, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['instance'] = self.request.user.profile  # Profile object
        return kwargs
```

Comment: I will take at look at that article, but for your code I'm getting this error: `Generic detail view ProfileSettings must be called with either an object pk or a slug.`

Comment: Usually UpdateView needs to be called using path `your_url/<int:pk>/` or  `your_url/<slug>/`. If you don't intend to use in that way, then please consider using `FormView` instead.

Comment: I dont intend to use it in that way, but the reason why I'm keeping UpdateView is because it can display the user's data when accessing the form. FormView doesnt do that

Comment: You can get the form data in FormView as well. Please see my updated answer

Comment: This works great, but in `get_form_kwargs` is there a way to return a blank form if the profile does not exist. Right now, it returns a `RelatedObjectDoesNotExist` error

Comment: You can use `kwargs['instance']=Profile.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).first()`